# SwiftUI "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" when making pop

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Good Evening,

Here I want to discuss one strange situation. I'm making app in SwiftUI, and problem beginning with modal navigation.

Here example of my code:

**CategoriesListView**

```
struct CategoriesListView: View {
@ObservedObject var viewModel: CategoriesListViewModel
@State private var searchedText = ""
@State private var showCancelButton: Bool = false
@GestureState private var dragOffset = CGSize.zero

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { [weak viewModel] geometry in
        NavigationView {
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    Image("bg_shape")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
                        .position(x:  geo.size.width / 2, y: geo.size.height / 4)
                }
                self.content(viewModel: viewModel)
            }.navigationBarTitle("Categories", displayMode: .automatic)
                .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.3))
                .navigationBarHidden(self.showCancelButton)
                .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                    viewModel?.dismiss.send(())
                }) {
                    Image("button_arrow")
                },trailing: Image("logo"))
                .gesture(DragGesture().updating(self.$dragOffset, body: { (value, state, transaction) in
                    if(value.startLocation.x < 20 && value.translation.width > 100) {
                        viewModel?.dismiss.send(())
                    }
                }))

        }
    }
}
```

**CategoryProductsListView**

```
struct CategoryProductsList: View {
@Environment(\.viewController) var viewRepresentative
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
@ObservedObject var viewModel: CategoryProductListViewModel
@State private var searchedText = ""
@State private var showCancelButton: Bool = false
@State private var showModal: Bool = false
@GestureState private var dragOffset = CGSize.zero

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { [weak viewModel] geometry in
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                Image("bg_shape")
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
                    .position(x: geo.size.width / 2, y: geo.size.height / 4)
            }
            self.content(viewModel: viewModel)
        }.navigationBarTitle("Products", displayMode: .automatic)
            .navigationBarHidden(self.showCancelButton)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                UITableView.appearance().rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                Image("button_arrow")
            },trailing: Image("logo"))
            .gesture(DragGesture().updating(self.$dragOffset, body: { (value, state, transaction) in
                if(value.startLocation.x < 20 && value.translation.width > 100) {
                    UITableView.appearance().rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
            }))
    }.blur(radius: self.showModal ? 4 : 0)
}
```

Here is example of my stack navigation:

**CategoriesListView -> CategoryProductsListView -> ProductDetailView**

On ProductDetaliView I have button, which dismissing screen.

```
 Button(action: {
     self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()}) {
        Image("button_close")
 }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()))
```

**Situation 1:**

*When I present modally **ProductDetailView**, and use to dismiss button, then I returning back to **CategoriesListView**, everything is ok.*

**Situation 2:** 
*When I present modally **ProductDetailView**, and use swipe down to dismiss screen, then I returning back to **CategoriesListView**, and it will crash app without any log on log screen.*

[image: StackTrace]
[image: StackTrace1]
[image: AppDelegate]

It seems to be a bug on Swift UI, but I didn't find any information about it. If you have any idea what it can be, please help.

Have a nice day!

**EDIT:**

After hours, I found a solution, problem was in changing appearance of UINavigationBar.

Closing question

Comment: The *Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION* exception is 99,99% a developer bug. Set the Exception Breakpoint to get more information.

Comment: @vadian I did it first before I wrote here question, and nothing. I selected all exceptions, and nothing :(

Comment: If the problem is solved, give the solution as an _answer_. Do not embed the answer in the question.

Comment: do help further the bug, click on the thread with the exception and in the console at the bottom type `$arg1`, that should output the actual error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours, I found a solution, problem was in changing appearance of UINavigationBar.

Closing question